# Why is the () in Haskell a Enum type but haven't implemented the succ function

Tags: exception, haskell, enums, ghc, typeclass

I find

```
Prelude> :i ()
data () = ()    -- Defined in `GHC.Tuple'
instance Bounded () -- Defined in `GHC.Enum'
instance Enum () -- Defined in `GHC.Enum'
instance Eq () -- Defined in `GHC.Classes'
instance Ord () -- Defined in `GHC.Classes'
instance Read () -- Defined in `GHC.Read'
instance Show () -- Defined in `GHC.Show'
```

So,that mean () is an instance of Enum, and should have implemented the `succ` function. However, when I tried `succ ()`,I got `*** Exception: Prelude.Enum.().succ: bad argument`

I searched the source code of `GHC.Tuple` where the type of () should be defined but `GHC.Tuple`

Answer (score 11):

The `succ` function is only defined for arguments which have a successor.

```
Prelude> succ False
True
Prelude> succ True
*** Exception: Prelude.Enum.Bool.succ: bad argument

Prelude> succ 0
1
Prelude> succ 1
2
Prelude> succ ((2^63 - 1) :: Int)
*** Exception: Prelude.Enum.succ{Int}: tried to take `succ' of maxBound

Prelude> succ ()
*** Exception: Prelude.Enum.().succ: bad argument
```

So the answer is: the function is implemented, it just (correctly) returns an error, always.

Comment: This is because the `Enum` typeclass is antiquated and does not follow modern best practices.  Partial functions are bad.

Comment: @PhilipJF: I'll have to disagree there.  Partial functions are a fact of life -- the type system is simply not powerful enough to allow us to express certain functions as total functions without jumping through hoops.

Comment: I wouldn't call using `Maybe` jumping through hoops. Modern best practices would give `succ` and `pred` the type `a -> Maybe a`, and add partial versions with longer names.

Comment: Accepting that, e.g., division on `Int` is a partial function is one thing, making functions partial for no good reason is another. The `Enum` instance for `()` is just painfully stupid and misguided, even beyond how terrible the `Enum` class itself is to begin with.

Comment: @C.A.McCann, from the point of view of an Haskell newbie's which I am, it'd be nice to see some links/references in support of the comments (e.g. _terrible the `Enum` class itself is to begin with_), as I would have much to learn from that.

Comment: @Enrico: there’s a general sentiment in Haskell that we should move towards total functions. Not everyone agrees, and it isn’t always reasonable, but Enum is a simple case where we could e.g. `succ :: a -> Maybe a`.